# If $a_n = a_{n-1}a_{n-3} + a_{n-2}^2$, then is it always divisible by $a_{n-4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

The [Somos Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos_sequence) are neat because they are integral yet contain a division operation.

If we consider the numerator $a_n = a_{n-1}a_{n-3} + a_{n-2}^2$ of the Somos-4 sequence, $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 1$, then is it always divisible by $a_{n-4}$?

Note that this is not obvious, since integrality in the orignal Somos-4 sequence implies that $a_{n-4}$ divides the numerator, $a_{n-4}$ and the numerator each built with respect to *that* sequence's previous elements and not with respect to the simpler sequence above.

Comment: I don't think you meant to define $a_4=1$, since $a_4$ is determined by the values $a_1,a_2,a_3$ as $2$.

Comment: I'm confused about the Somos sequence part. The Somos-4 sequence is $a_na_{n-4}=a_{n-1}a_{n-3}+a_{n-2}^2$. How is the above express the "denominator"? Or are you defining a completely new sequence via your recurrence?

Comment: @AlexR. I meant numerator, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Working out the first few terms of the recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1} a_{n-3} + a_{n-2}^2$, we get

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n & a_n \\ \hline
1 & 1\\
2 & 1\\
3 & 1\\
4 & 2\\
5 & 3\\
6 & 7\\
7 & 23\\
8 & 118\\
9 & 1355\\
\end{array}
$$
from which we see $a_{5} = 3$ and $a_9 = 1355$, but $3 \nmid 1355$.

In fact for $n \leq 50$, $a_{n-4} \mid a_n$ only for $n=5,6,7,8$.